# Run error when using docker with SQL Server (odbc package)

Tags: r, sql-server, docker, odbc

I am trying to use the odbc package to connect to a SQL Server database for my application. When I run it locally, for example, on Rstudio, it does work just fine but when I try to run it on shiny proxy, or in a container directly, it doesn't work.

Here is the code of the dockerfile

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base

#update all packages
RUN apt-get update

#upgrade
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

#install additional packages
RUN apt install gpg-agent -y unixodbc apt-utils curl unixodbc-dev \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.1 \
    libmpfr-dev \
    libxml2-dev

# R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('Rmpfr', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinydashboard', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('xml2')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('rvest')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('plotly', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reactable', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tidyverse')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('DBI')"

#get msodbcsql17 and install it
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools

#install packaes needed for running the app
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('odbc', 'data.table'))"

# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/app_src
COPY app_src /root/app_src

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app_src')"]
```

And here is the line where I connect to the data base

```
db_Inv <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", Server = "10.200.16.8", Database = "Investigacion", UID = "*****", PWD = "*****", Port = 1433)
```

As you can see, on the Dockerfile there are some lines about installing ms sql server drivers. I run the same lines on rstudio console and everything work just fine.

The problem when I run the code on shinyproxy or in the container directly is this:

> Warning: Error in : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
>
> 57: 
> Error : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your `docker run` command; specifically, are you using something like `-p 10.200.16.8:1433:1433` to map the internal port to the port on that specific address/interface? (Ref: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: I am running the container like this : sudo docker run -p 3838:3838 appgdm1. I can access to it but then it freezes and throw the error I wrote. If I specify -p 1433:1433 I can´t even access to the app

Comment: Try removing the `Port` attribute and specify `Server = "10.200.16.8,1433"`

Comment: I misread the specific port/application, I think @DanGuzman likely has it right.